# How can I compute probablity of second event knowing the probablity of first event?

Tags: probability, inequality, solution-verification

**Lemma 1.1** $$\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}) \leq \mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L}}) + \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right) $$

Assume an event
$E_{1} : \mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}) \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Now,

\begin{align}
    \nonumber\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}) - \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right) \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right)\\
    \underbrace{\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L}}) \leq  \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right)}_{E_{2}} && \text{Using Lemma 1.1}
\end{align}

I know,

\begin{align}
\nonumber &\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}_{L, \epsilon}: \underbrace{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2}}_{\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}})} \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \\
& \leq 4  \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3} 2^{2}}\right)+2 \cdot \left(60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)^{p} \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2} 2^{2}}\right)
\end{align}

So can I write for event $E_{2}$,
\begin{align}
\nonumber &\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \underbrace{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2}}_{\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L}})} \leq \sigma^{2} -\underbrace{\frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right)}_{\frac{\epsilon}{h}}\right)  \\
&\leq 4  \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3} h^{2}}\right)+2 \cdot \left(60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)^{p} \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2} h^{2}}\right)
\end{align}

Kindly verify my proof.

Comment: I may not speak for everyone, but it's very hard for me to verify anything about this proof in this form. What problem are you trying to solve? What does your notation mean? Some words to explain this would help tremendously.

Comment: I know the probablity for event E1. I need to know the probablity for event E2. SO primarily I want how can I say - If my event E2 holds then E1 will also hold

Comment: What's $\mathcal L$? What's $f_{W_l}$? What are $\epsilon, b$ and how do they relate to anything else? What's the norm $||\cdot||_{\infty}$? What's $JW$? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are in wrong direction.

Assume an event
$E_{1} : \mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L}})  \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}- \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right)$

From Lemma 1.1, we can write,

$\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L}}) + \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right) \geq  \mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}})$

Now,

\begin{align}
    \nonumber\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L}}) + \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right) &\leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right) + \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right)\\
     &\leq  \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2} ..........(2)
\end{align}

From Lemma $1.1$ and equation $2$ we can write,

$$\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L,\epsilon}}) \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

So we can write,
\begin{align}
\nonumber &\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \underbrace{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2}}_{\mathcal{L}(f_{w_{L}})} \leq \sigma^{2} -\underbrace{\frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{3} \cdot \left(JW +||f_{0}||_{\infty} +  b\right)}_{\frac{\epsilon}{h}}\right)  \\
&\leq 4  \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3} h^{2}}\right)+2 \cdot \left(60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)^{p} \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2} h^{2}}\right)
\end{align}